# Silent install of SQL Server Express with Advanced Tools

Tags: sql, wpf, sql-server-2014-express, silent-installer

I am trying to silent install SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU) through a WPF application but I'm having some difficulties.

When the application runs it extracts the setup files, but seems to just skip all the rest and doesn't install anything.  I also get no error messages.  Below are the arguments i'm passing in.  Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
var process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = $"{_installationSoftwarePath}\\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe",
                        Arguments = $"  /QS /u /x:\"C:\\{Guid.NewGuid()}\" /ACTION=Install /ENU /FEATURES=SQLEngine,RS,Tools /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=***** /HIDECONSOLE /SQLSVCACCOUNT=\"NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM\" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /TCPENABLED=1 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=%USERDOMAIN%\\Administrator",
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    }
                };

                process.Start();

                process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You have used the `/QS` options which will suppress the errors, try removing that option and running it to see if you can see the errors. See this [link from Microsoft] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)

Comment: Turns out that there were a lot of "Required" arguments that weren't set.  I changed it to the 2016 version of sql and reviewed the parameters from microsofts site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx).  This fixed the issue.